# Proper formatting of symmetric algorithm secret key

Tags: implementation, pgp

Given this description from RFC 4880 sec 5.1:

> The value "m" in the above formulas is derived from the session key as
> follows. First, the session key is prefixed with a one-octet algorithm
> identifier that specifies the symmetric encryption algorithm used to
> encrypt the following Symmetrically Encrypted Data Packet. Then a
> two-octet checksum is appended, which is equal to the sum of the
> preceding session key octets, not including the algorithm identifier,
> modulo 65536. This value is then encoded as described in PKCS#1 block
> encoding EME-PKCS1-v1_5 in Section 7.2.1 of [RFC3447] to form the "m"
> value used in the formulas above. See [Section 13.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-13.1.1) of this
> document for notes on OpenPGP’s use of PKCS#1.

and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11301425/what-does-this-ambiguous-pronoun-represent-in-the-text-of-rfc-4880) guess at what the pronoun `this` in the passage means, what is the proper way to format `m`? The description seems somewhat vague at where everything goes.

```
13.1.1.  EME-PKCS1-v1_5-ENCODE

   Input:

   k  = the length in octets of the key modulus

   M  = message to be encoded, an octet string of length mLen, where
        mLen <= k - 11

   Output:

   EM = encoded message, an octet string of length k

   Error:   "message too long"

     1. Length checking: If mLen > k - 11, output "message too long" and
        stop.

     2. Generate an octet string PS of length k - mLen - 3 consisting of
        pseudo-randomly generated nonzero octets.  The length of PS will
        be at least eight octets.

     3. Concatenate PS, the message M, and other padding to form an
        encoded message EM of length k octets as

        EM = 0x00 || 0x02 || PS || 0x00 || M.

     4. Output EM.
```

Given this data:

```
ElGamal modulus p has 512 bits -> 64 octets
Symmetric key algorithm = AES128 = 0x07
secret key = 0x0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef
checksum = 2 * (0x01 + 0x23 + 0x45 + 0x67 + 0x89 + 0xab + 0xcd + 0xef) = 0x780
```

At first, i thought it was: `"0002" + random_non_zero_data + "00070123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0780"`, but when i try to decrypt the data using a real PGP program, it says the key checksum failed.

Then, I get contradictory data from PGPdump: `m = sym alg(1 byte) + checksum(2 bytes) + PKCS-1 block type 02`, so i tried `"070780" + "0002" + random_non_zero_data + "0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef"`, but that didnt work either ("exception decrypting secret key").

What is the correct `m` i should be getting?

Comment: The code you are trying to rewrite exists in gnupg-2.0.19/g10/seskey.c, function encode_session_key, available [here](http://www.gnupg.org/download/index.en.html), and it seems the way you did it first is right.